# How can I find or make executable file of python on my macOS El Capitan

Tags: macos

I can't find executable python file on my **macOS El Capitan**.

How should I find or make it?

Comment: This is a Google Question, but go into Python IDEL,  File, New File, then start typing and save it.

Comment: what should I type there to make the Xcode suitable for Python?

Comment: Link I got from Google. You want to run python in Xcode?   https://medium.com/sourleangchhean/using-xcode-to-execute-pythons-code-98be65c1ea8a

Comment: You should run 'which python' from the command line. It will tell you which version of python is currently ready to run.  After you run that please let me know what is written on the terminal window.

Comment: i would not try to run python frpm Xcode!!!

Comment: Macs come with Python installed already. You may want a newer version like 3.6.5. that's the version I'm running. If you haven't loaded a new python yourself you may want to do it using Anaconda.  What are your plans with Python?

Comment: @EzLo, regarding your edit, it may be better to fix a spelling than to highlight a typo in bold.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't installed a newer version of python. If true I would suggest you load python using the [Anaconda Distribution.](https://www.anaconda.com/download/#macos)  There are instructions to install on your mac. Once installed, python can be run from the command line by typing `python filename.py` where filename.py is the name of the python script you want to run. Be sure you are in same directory as filename or you'll have to include the file path as well.

Disclaimer: I am not, nor have I ever been, an employee of Anaconda.